# Jest how to do OR / try catch case for snapshot testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, snapshot

This does not work

```js
describe('Upgrading', () => {
  it('updates BOTH version and license fields', () => {
    const version = '1.0.0';
    const license = '123..abc';

    try {
      expect(version).toMatchSnapshot();
      expect(license).toMatchSnapshot();
    } catch {
      expect(version).not.toMatchSnapshot();
      expect(license).not.toMatchSnapshot();
    }
  });
});
```

If one change I want to be sure that both change. otherwise they should be unchanged.

Changing the `version` to `"1.0.1" makes the test fail in the try block and not in the catch block.

Comment: Put them in the same expect? `expect(\`${version},${license}\`)` otherwise they'll be matched independently

Comment: But is should pass if both values are changed..?

Comment: How can a snapshot be changed if the code doesn't change?

Comment: You have a point that a challenge would be to get both snapshot updated if both values has changed.. the test is to make sure you don't forget to update both values (origin from different files)